# Hbase REST skips authorization

Tags: rest, authorization, hbase, kerberos

I have set up Hbase with Kerberos authentication and everything seems to work fine (shell and hue abide table grants), but I can't seem to get REST to follow authorization. No mater what as long as I am authenticated I can select anything i want.

I can not seem to find any solid articles about it, the only thing i could find was authentication which works just fine.

Can someone explain how authorization works and is set up in Hbase REST?

I have configurations set up as explained in this article:
https://developer.ibm.com/hadoop/2016/05/12/hbase-rest-gateway-security/

Thank you.

Comment: In other words, the REST service connects to HBase with its Kerberos service account, not with your own client creds...?

Comment: Yes. It seems like it is executing the command with a specific user defined in properties. But than the whole REST service just has one single authorization. Which really makes no sense.

Comment: IMHO that REST service is a very lame, band-aid solution. Use it only for lame apps that cannot use a proper HBase client lib.